# Yesod - Data constructor 'Key' is not in scope

Tags: haskell, module, package, yesod

I am trying the following simple function:

```
handler loadEntities (Key $ PersistInt64 1)
```

but I don't have this `Key` function in my scope, so I get the following error:

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘Key’
```

Could somebody tell me what import is missing, and why it doesn't come together with scaffolding?

Comment: `Key` is a data type, not a constructor....  There is a way to create a key from an integral type, but I have to go look that function up again, forgot at the moment.  Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: OK, I think it is toSqlKey....  I might try this out, and if it works, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Yup, found it in a bunch of code that I wrote a while ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a Key from an integral type, use

```
toSqlKey (fromIntegral value)
```

Comment: I got the following error: `Not in scope: ‘toSqlKey’` ... I did search on google to find out where  it is from, but I didn't find

Comment: Now I found, it is from `Database.Persist.Sql`